# Adding scrollbar to table body in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, tree

I would like to know how can I add the scrollbars *only* to the `table` `body`, and not to the `table` `head`. In the below example and in this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/idRmsdNtiKiaj8LroeSK?p=preview), when the scrollbars are added, they control both `table` `head` and `table` `body`. I want the horizontal scrollbar for both `header` and `body` but vertical scrollbar only to `body`.

html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body data-ng-app="testApp" data-ng-controller="treeTable">
<div  class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="tableheight ">
  <table class="treetable-nested childtable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- <th >
          <input data-ng-checked="(list | selected).length == list.length" data-ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes($event)" type="checkbox" />
        </th> -->
        <th class="cell-members">
         <input data-ng-checked="(list | selected).length == list.length" data-ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes($event)" type="checkbox" /> Name
        </th>
        <th class="cell-members">
          Version
        </th>
        <th class="cell-members">
          Size
        </th>
        <th class="cell-members">
        Modified By
        </th>
        <th class="cell-members">
        Labels
        </th>
        <th class="cell-members">
        Description
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="newRepo" style="font-size:12px" data-ng-class="{opened: item.opened}" data-ng-include="&#39;table_tree.html&#39;" data-ng-repeat="item in list"></tbody>
  </table>
    </div>
  <script id="table_tree.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <tr ng-class="{parent: item.children}" ng-init="parentScope = $parent.$parent; initCheckbox(item, parentScope.item)">

      <td class="cell-name top-border" ng-if="level &amp;&amp; level &gt; 1">
      <span style="padding-left: 30px" >&nbsp;  <input ng-change="toggleCheckbox(item, parentScope)" ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" />
        {{item.name}} </span>
      </td>
<td class="cell-name top-border" ng-if=" &#40;&#33;level &amp;&amp; level &lt;&#61; 1 &#41; &#124;&#124 &#40;level &amp;&amp; level &lt;&#61; 1&#41;">
        <span style="padding-left:11px" ng-click="item.opened = !item.opened"></span>&nbsp;<input ng-change="toggleCheckbox(item, parentScope)" ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" />
        {{item.name}}
      </td>

<td class="cell-name top-border" ng-if="&#33;level">
       <span class="indent" ng-click="item.opened = !item.opened">&nbsp;<input ng-change="toggleCheckbox(item, parentScope)" ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" />
        {{item.name}} </span>
      </td>

      <td class="cell-name">
        {{item.Version}} 
      </td>
      <td class="cell-name">
        {{item.Size}}
      </td>
      <td class="cell-name">
        {{item.ModifiedBy}}
      </td>
    <td class="cell-name">
        {{item.Labels}}
      </td>
<td class="cell-name">
        {{item.Description}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="children" ng-if="item.children &amp;&amp; item.children.length &gt; 0">
      <td colspan="6">
        <table class="childtable">
          <tbody style="font-size:12px" ng-class="{opened: item.opened}" ng-include="&#39;table_tree.html&#39;" ng-init="level = level + 1" ng-repeat="item in item.children"></tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could take a data-table approach. They hide the original table headers and replace them outside/above the `<div class="tableheight">` in their own table.

Comment: you mean to use datatables.net? This would take lot of development time and not sure if i can do something similar using datatables.

Comment: Yes. What I meant was you could attempt to copy their style/approach. If to much work to add it to your project. The CSS by @NataliaWilliams would be the other best approach I was about to post same thing. LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WAQWeCUImi4m1MXRH3Js?p=preview)

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css" /> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body data-ng-app="testApp" data-ng-controller="treeTable">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <div class="table-outer-wrapper">
        <table class="treetable-nested childtable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <!-- <th >
          <input data-ng-checked="(list | selected).length == list.length" data-ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes($event)" type="checkbox" />
        </th> -->
              <th class="cell-members">
                <div>
                  <input data-ng-checked="(list | selected).length == list.length" data-ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes($event)" type="checkbox" /> Name
                </div>
              </th>
              <th class="cell-members">
                <div>
                  Version
                </div>
              </th>
              <th class="cell-members">
                <div>
                  Size
                </div>
              </th>
              <th class="cell-members">
                <div>
                  Modified By
                </div>
              </th>
              <th class="cell-members">
                <div>
                  Labels
                </div>
              </th>
              <th class="cell-members">
                <div>
                  Description
                </div>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="newRepo" style="font-size:12px" data-ng-class="{opened: item.opened}" data-ng-include="&#39;table_tree.html&#39;" data-ng-repeat="item in list"></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script id="table_tree.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <tr ng-class="{parent: item.children}" ng-init="parentScope = $parent.$parent; initCheckbox(item, parentScope.item)">
      <td class="cell-name top-border" ng-if="level &amp;&amp; level &gt; 1">
        <span style="padding-left: 30px">&nbsp;  <input ng-change="toggleCheckbox(item, parentScope)" ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" />
        {{item.name}} </span>
      </td>
      <td class="cell-name top-border" ng-if=" &#40;&#33;level &amp;&amp; level &lt;&#61; 1 &#41; &#124;&#124 &#40;level &amp;&amp; level &lt;&#61; 1&#41;">
        <span style="padding-left:11px" ng-click="item.opened = !item.opened"></span>&nbsp;
        <input ng-change="toggleCheckbox(item, parentScope)" ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" /> {{item.name}}
      </td>
      <td class="cell-name top-border" ng-if="&#33;level">
        <span class="indent" ng-click="item.opened = !item.opened">&nbsp;<input ng-change="toggleCheckbox(item, parentScope)" ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" />
        {{item.name}} </span>
      </td>
      <td class="cell-name">
        {{item.Version}}
      </td>
      <td class="cell-name">
        {{item.Size}}
      </td>
      <td class="cell-name">
        {{item.ModifiedBy}}
      </td>
      <td class="cell-name">
        {{item.Labels}}
      </td>
      <td class="cell-name">
        {{item.Description}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="children" ng-if="item.children &amp;&amp; item.children.length &gt; 0">
      <td colspan="6">
        <table class="childtable">
          <tbody style="font-size:12px" ng-class="{opened: item.opened}" ng-include="&#39;table_tree.html&#39;" ng-init="level = level + 1" ng-repeat="item in item.children"></tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
.childtable {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.treetable-nested {
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.treetable-nested th .treetable-nested td {
    padding: 0;
}

.treetable-nested td {
    background: #F9F9F9;
}

.treetable-nested td + td {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.treetable-nested td {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

.treetable-nested td[colspan] {
    border: none;
}

.treetable-nested .cell-input {
    width: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
}

.treetable-nested .cell-members {
    width: 10%;
}

.treetable-nested .indent {}

.treetable-nested .parent > .cell-name {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.treetable-nested .cell-name {}

.treetable-nested .parent > .cell-name > .indent:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f054";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.treetable-nested .children {
    display: none;
}

.treetable-nested .opened > tr > .cell-name > .indent:before {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.treetable-nested .opened > .children {
    display: table-row;
}




.main-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 37px;
}

.table-outer-wrapper {
    height: 150px;
    overflow:auto;
}

.table-outer-wrapper table {
    min-width: 800px;
}
.table-head {
    height: 37px;
}
.table-head > div {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    padding: 9px 0px;
}
.table-head-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
(function () {
    var app, list;
    list = [
        {
            name: 'Repo 1',
            opened: true,
            Version:'Current Version',
            Size:'Repo Size',
            ModifiedBy:'sashi',
            Labels:'repo1',
            Description:'',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'Bundle 1',
                    opened: true,
                    Version:'Current Version',
                    Size:'Repo Size',
                    ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                    Labels:'repo1',
                    Description:'',
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'Comp 1',
                            title: 'Leader',
                            Version:'Current Version',
                                Size:'Repo Size',
                                    ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                                    Labels:'repo1',
                                    Description:''
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Comp 2',
                            title: 'Senior F2E',
                            Version:'Current Version',
                                Size:'Repo Size',
                                    ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                                    Labels:'repo1',
                                    Description:''
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Comp 3',
                            title: 'Junior F2E',
                            Version:'Current Version',
                            Size:'Repo Size',
                                ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                                Labels:'repo1',
                                Description:''
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Bundle 2',
                    opened: true,
                    Version:'Current Version',
                    Size:'Repo Size',
                    ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                    Labels:'repo1',
                    Description:'',
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'Comp 1',
                            title: 'Leader',
                            Version:'Current Version',
                            Size:'Repo Size',
                            ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                            Labels:'repo1',
                            Description:''
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Comp 2',
                            title: 'Intern',
                            Version:'Current Version',
                            Size:'Repo Size',
                            ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                            Labels:'repo1',
                            Description:''
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Bundle 3',
                    opened: true,
                    Version:'Current Version',
                    Size:'Repo Size',
                    ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                    Labels:'repo1',
                    Description:'',
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'Comp 1',
                            title: 'Leader',
                            Version:'Current Version',
                            Size:'Repo Size',
                            ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                            Labels:'repo1',
                            Description:''
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Comp 2',
                            title: 'Intern',
                            Version:'Current Version',
                            Size:'Repo Size',
                            ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                            Labels:'repo1',
                            Description:''
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Repo 2',
            Version:'Current Version',
            Size:'Repo Size',
            ModifiedBy:'sashi',
            Labels:'repo1',
            Description:'',
            children: [{
                    name: 'Bundle 1',
                    title: 'Designer',
                    Version:'Current Version',
                    Size:'Repo Size',
                    ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                    Labels:'repo1',
                    Description:''
                }]
        },
        {
            name: 'Repo 3',
            Version:'Current Version',
            Size:'Repo Size',
            ModifiedBy:'sashi',
            Labels:'repo1',
            Description:'',
            children: [{
                    name: 'Bundle 1',
                    title: 'Robot',
                    Version:'Current Version',
                    Size:'Repo Size',
                    ModifiedBy:'sashi',
                    Labels:'repo1',
                    Description:'',
                }]
        }
    ];
    app = angular.module('testApp', []).controller('treeTable', [
        '$scope',
        '$filter',
        function ($scope, $filter) {
            $scope.list = list;

            $scope.save = function() {
                $scope.repoList = [];
                $scope.bundleList = [];
                $scope.componentList = [];
                $scope.selectedItems = [];

                function checkChildren(c) {
                    angular.forEach(c.children, function (c) {
                        if(c.selected) {
                            $scope.bundleList.push(c.name);
                            $scope.selectedItems.push(c.name);
                        }
                        checkComponents (c);
                    });
                }
                function checkComponents(c) {
                    angular.forEach(c.children, function (c) {
                       if (c.selected){
                          $scope.componentList.push(c.name);
                          $scope.selectedItems.push(c.name);
                       }
                    //    checkChildren(c);
                    });
               }

                angular.forEach($scope.list, function(value, key) {
                    alert(value.name);
                    if(value.selected) {
                        $scope.repoList.push(value.name);
                    }
                    checkChildren(value);
               });
                console.log($scope.repoList);
                console.log($scope.bundleList);
                console.log($scope.componentList);
                console.log($scope.selectedItems);
            };
            $scope.toggleAllCheckboxes = function ($event) {
                var i, item, len, ref, results, selected;
                selected = $event.target.checked;
                //alert(selected);
                ref = $scope.list;
                results = [];
                for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
                    /*if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
                        break;
                    }*/
                    item = ref[i];
                    item.selected = selected;
                    if (item.children != null) {
                        results.push($scope.$broadcast('changeChildren', item));
                    } else {
                        results.push(void 0);
                    }
                    //console.log();
                }
                //window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
                return results;
            };
            $scope.initCheckbox = function (item, parentItem) {
                //alert(parentItem.selected);
                return item.selected = parentItem && parentItem.selected || item.selected || false;
            };
            $scope.toggleCheckbox = function (item, parentScope) {
                if (item.children != null) {
                    $scope.$broadcast('changeChildren', item);
                }
                if (parentScope.item != null) {
                    return $scope.$emit('changeParent', parentScope);
                }
            };
            $scope.$on('changeChildren', function (event, parentItem) {
                var child, i, len, ref, results;
                ref = parentItem.children;
                results = [];
                for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
                    /*if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(2)) {
                        break;
                    }*/
                    child = ref[i];
                    child.selected = parentItem.selected;
                    if (child.children != null) {
                        results.push($scope.$broadcast('changeChildren', child));
                    } else {
                        results.push(void 0);
                    }
                }
               // window.CP.exitedLoop(2);
                return results;
            });
            return $scope.$on('changeParent', function (event, parentScope) {
                var children;
                children = parentScope.item.children;
                parentScope.item.selected = $filter('selected')(children).length === children.length;
                parentScope = parentScope.$parent.$parent;
                if (parentScope.item != null) {
                    return $scope.$broadcast('changeParent', parentScope);
                }
            });
        }
    ]);
    app.filter('selected', [
        '$filter',
        function ($filter) {
            return function (files) {
                return $filter('filter')(files, { selected: true });
            };
        }
    ]);
}.call(this));


function resize_table() {
    var reference_td, head_padding;
    var scrollbar_width = $('.table-outer-wrapper')[0].offsetHeight - $('.table-outer-wrapper')[0].clientHeight;

    $('.table-head').width($('.table-outer-wrapper table').width());


    $('.table-head-wrapper').width($('.table-outer-wrapper').width() - scrollbar_width);
    $('.table-head > div').each(function(i,e){
        reference_td = $('.table-outer-wrapper table tr td:nth-child(' + (i +1)+ ')');
        head_padding = parseInt($(e).css('padding-left'), 10);
        console.log(head_padding);
        $(e).width(reference_td.outerWidth() - (head_padding*2));
    })

}

function scroll_table(){
    var sx = $('.table-outer-wrapper').scrollLeft();
    $('.table-head').css('transform', 'translateX(-' + sx + 'px)');
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main-wrapper').prepend('<div class="table-head-wrapper"><div class="table-head"></div></div>');

    $('.cell-members > div').each(function(i,e){
        $(e).appendTo('.table-head');
    });

    resize_table();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        resize_table();
    });

    $('.table-outer-wrapper').scroll(function() {
        scroll_table();
    });

})
```

Comment: I dont want the text of each cell to be fixed in the table. My requirement is I want the horizontal scrollbar for both header and body but vertical scrollbar only to body. Any help on this?

Comment: In the Updated plunkr am not able to see vertical scroll bar and not able to move horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I see! I'm trying another approach. This time I'm completely detaching the table head from the table body. This seems to be a simpler approach. Please have a look.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Due to some jquery problem in my application the above jquery is throwing error. Can i  know whether i can do same thing from angularjs? Any help on this?

Comment: @shaaa do you think you could create a Plunker to showcase the error?

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

```
.tableheight {
    /* leave some room for the table head height */
    padding-top: 38px;
}
.childtable thead {
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Williams this is working if the table is at the top of the page. My tree table is in middle of page. Any other help should be great.

Comment: on adding this code, the horizontal scroll bar is not coming. Any other help would be great.

Comment: @shaaa Would you consider using jQuery?

Comment: Sure. Will consider it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Make overflow-x as hidden which hides the scrollbar in the x-axis.

https://plnkr.co/edit/jOR3MD4Lf8ysgxVULmar?p=preview
@charset "UTF-8";
.childtable {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.treetable-nested {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.tableheight {
  height: 280px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.tableheight::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.tableheight::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.tableheight::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #737373;
}

.treetable-nested th .treetable-nested td {
  padding: 0;
}

.treetable-nested td {
  background: #F9F9F9;
}

.treetable-nested th + th,
.treetable-nested th + td,
.treetable-nested td + th,
.treetable-nested td + td {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.treetable-nested td {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

.treetable-nested td[colspan] {
  border: none;
}

.treetable-nested .cell-input {
  width: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}

.treetable-nested .cell-members {
  width: 10%;
}

.treetable-nested .indent {}

.treetable-nested .parent > .cell-name {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.treetable-nested .cell-name {}

.treetable-nested .parent > .cell-name > .indent:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f054";
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.treetable-nested .children {
  display: none;
}

.treetable-nested .newRepo {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  /*this is used for giving space between each repo*/
}

.treetable-nested .opened > tr > .cell-name > .indent:before {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.treetable-nested .opened > .children {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: it dint solve my question. I want overflow-y only to table body. In the example it is added for both table body as well as table head.

Comment: Hi Shaa, I understood that you did not want horizontal scrollbar to your table i.e. overflow-x. Did you check the plunkr?http://plnkr.co/edit/jOR3MD4Lf8ysgxVULmar?p=preview

Comment: @Rachel The user want the scroll bar. But he wants the table headings to show even when the table is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

You could make two tables, one with only table headers and one with the table bodies. And then you overflow-y the 2nd table containing the tbody's. Plnkr: [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0qETK6XW2hKRO2cohWFp?p=preview)

```
<table class="treetable-nested childtable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <!-- <th >
      <input data-ng-checked="(list | selected).length == list.length" data-ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes($event)" type="checkbox" />
    </th> -->
    <th class="cell-members">
     <input data-ng-checked="(list | selected).length == list.length" data-ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes($event)" type="checkbox" /> Name
    </th>
    <th class="cell-members">
      Version
    </th>
    <th class="cell-members">
      Size
    </th>
    <th class="cell-members">
    Modified By
    </th>
    <th class="cell-members">
    Labels
    </th>
    <th class="cell-members">
    Description
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

```
<div class="fakeTable">
<table class="treetable-nested childtable2">
  <tbody class="newRepo" style="font-size:12px" data-ng-class="{opened: item.opened}" data-ng-include="&#39;table_tree.html&#39;" data-ng-repeat="item in list">
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

You remove the overflow from .tableheight class in your css and add this

```
.childtable2 {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display:table;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.fakeTable{
  max-height:150px;
  display:block;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: @ K Town the code given is working for the fixed header. But if you observe the table it is breaking child rows. Please let me know any other changes also need to be made.

Comment: @shaaa Sorry for not checking that twice. I've edited the plunker and answer, it should now work as intended.